# PHP Table Format

Tags: php

I've put together the following code which creates a table upon a selection being made with a drop down menu.

```
echo "<table>";
$result=mysql_query($query);
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th>Find Name:</th>";
echo "<th>Find Description:</th>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>".$rows['findname']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$rows['finddescription']."</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

The problem I've got is that for each record that is returned the 'headers' are repeated. The live page can be found [here](http://www.mapmyfinds.co.uk/development/ajaxfunction.php). I just wonder whether someone could perhaps take a look at this please and tell me where I've gone wrong.

Apologies for the really simple question, but I've been looking at this for a while and I just can't find the answer. I think it just needs a fresh pair of eyes to look at it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th>Find Name:</th>";
echo "<th>Find Description:</th>";
echo "</tr>";
$result=mysql_query($query);
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$rows['findname']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$rows['finddescription']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    }
echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this, you just need to get headers out of while loop

```
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th>Find Name:</th>";
echo "<th>Find Description:</th>";
echo "</tr>";

$result=mysql_query($query);
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>".$rows['findname']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$rows['finddescription']."</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 4):

The answer is obvious, you are repeating the output of the headers in the loop. Move the

```
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
```

after the first

```
echo "</tr>";
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to put the headers outside of the while loop:

```
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th>Find Name:</th>";
echo "<th>Find Description:</th>";
echo "</tr>";

$result = mysql_query($query);

while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $rows['findname'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $rows['finddescription'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 3):

Your headers are being repeated because you are writing them inside the loop, *for each row* returned by the query. You simply need to move your headers outside the loop so they're only written once, before the rows returned by the query start printing:

```
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th>Find Name:</th>";
echo "<th>Find Description:</th>";
echo "</tr>";

$result=mysql_query($query);
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>".$rows['findname']."</td>";
  echo "<td>".$rows['finddescription']."</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 3):

headers are repeating becasue they are in while loop, it should work well

```
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th>Find Name:</th>";
echo "<th>Find Description:</th>";
echo "</tr>";
$result=mysql_query($query);
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>".$rows['findname']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$rows['finddescription']."</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 2):

Change to:

```
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th>Find Name:</th>";
echo "<th>Find Description:</th>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo "<td>".$rows['findname']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$rows['finddescription']."</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```